# Intercepting outgoing http requests in Android

Tags: android

I want to intercept outgoing http requests which are sent via any Android application before their actual processing gets start. Is there any way to listen to ports or are there any broadcasted intents sent out so that such http requests get notified.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool called wireshark which you can use to monitor all incoming and outgoing packets on your computer.  Set it up to filter out all traffic other than http.

Comment: I don't want any existing tool but I want to develop my own tool so please suggest me any book of android for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following tools:

- [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/)
- [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to get a proxy server: http://transproxy.sourceforge.net/ is supposedly compatible with Android, though I've personally never seen it work. You could then conceivably monitor what's passing through the proxy. Very very very messy, though, and dubious whether you could make it work with any kind of ease/reliability on a stock Android device.

Good Luck With That.

Comment: is it possible to do that without root?